# How to set primary id of one collection as secondary id of another collection in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am building a blog site (using angular at front , node at back and mongoDB) where I want to display blogs corresponding to their particular category.

I have 3 different categories for blogs. I have created two collections : one for category and another one for blogs. In the blogs collection I want to use a field named c_id which should be equal to id of the category collection. So when I click on a particular category it displays blogs of that category only.

Answer (score 0):

In your Blog collection schema you can define a field as c_id or categoryId as below:

```
var BlogSchema = new Schema({
        _id: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            auto: true,
        },
        blogTitle: {
           type: String
        },
        anyField: {
            type: String
        },
        categoryId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"categories",              // Name of your category collection
            required: true,
        },
});
```

To fetch all blogs along with category name you can try query as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: {
            from: "categories",             // Name of the foreign collection
            let: { "cId": "$categoryId" },  
            pipeline:[
                { 
                  $match: { 
                       $expr: { 
                          $eq: ["$_id", "$$cId"] 
                       } 
                  } 
                },
                {
                   $project: {
                       categoryName: 1
                   }
                }  
            ],
           as: "categoryInfo"
       }
    }
])
```